# Communication between third-User and my Server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am looking for the best way to setup communication between user who uses my application and my own server.

The thing is that I am creating application with licensing and I have to receive information by third-User when he connected and IP addresses he connected from.

But, I don't know should I use one more connection string and send those information to my **MS SQL Server** I have in my company from his workplace or I should upload `.txt` files on my web server? What is the best way to make this communication possible?

Comment: Hm.. I'm not sure if I should VTC this question as `to broad`, `opinion-based` or `unclear`.

Comment: Why not a web service which you periodically "ping" via a `Timer`? I'm assuming you don't need a constant connection, rather just a periodic status check.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner basically because that's happening just once per start.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Why would you say this is To broad? I mean I just asked which way is better/faster and more secure, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the requirements are a bit vague, based on what seem to need I would approach this with a web service. This WS would provide the means to communicate with your SQL server without exposing SQL itself to the internet.

Your web service could, for example, have a call which accepts the following information:

- Product being requested
- Information needed from the local client (machine name, etc.)
- Existing authentication ticket previously issued (if required)

Your method could then take this information, process it in SQL, and then return whether or not a license is available along with an authentication ticket (if needed).

On the client side, if your application only needs to hit this service once then you can just call it on connection/load. Otherwise if you need to periodically hit the licensing WS you could use a `Timer`.

```
Dim licenseCheck As New Timer
licenseCheck.Interval = 60000 ' Check every minute.
AddHandler licenseCheck.Tick AddressOf CheckLicense

Private Sub CheckLicense(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Call license web service and act accordingly.
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I was about to ignore using web service since I am not really familiar with creating/using them at all.

Comment: @Hoh - For something like this, it is worth learning. For the most part yours would be very basic (just a function which does some DB communication). You definitely do not want to expose your SQL database to the internet.

Comment: Since I have no idea what web service can do, can you tell me so I will make my WebService to connect to my MS SQL Server, right? If that's true, that means I will just use web service to connect it on (pull information) other than using another connection string to connect to the same place

Comment: @Hoh - Essentially you make a WS which handles all licensing validation. In the config file of your WS you would set the connection string to your DB and all communication the client does to your DB (i.e. the license check) would be done through the WS. The actual code you use to do the DB actions would the same as what you would do your client. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87h5xz7x(v=vs.90).aspx